# Has PackageLoader changed with Jinja2 (3.0.1) and Python3 (3.9.5)?

Tags: jinja2, macos-big-sur, python-3.9

I'm using `Jinja2 (3.0.1)`, `Python3 (3.9.5)`, and `macOS (11.3.1)`.

These lines used to work:

```
from jinja2 import Environment, PackageLoader
e = Environment(loader = PackageLoader("__main__", "."))
```

but now produce:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/downing/Dropbox/jinja2/Jinja2.py", line 36, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/downing/Dropbox/jinja2/Jinja2.py", line 31, in main
    e = Environment(loader = PackageLoader("__main__", "."))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 286, in __init__
    spec = importlib.util.find_spec(package_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/util.py", line 114, in find_spec
    raise ValueError('{}.__spec__ is None'.format(name))
ValueError: __main__.__spec__ is None
```

Answer (score 1):

The `PackageLoader` docs [say](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#jinja2.PackageLoader):

> *Changed in version 3.0:* No longer uses setuptools as a dependency.

which seems significant.

`__main__.__spec__` [can be](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#main-spec) `None` if `__main__` isn't imported from a module.  Probably `python -m Jinja2` would still work for you, even if `python Jinja2.py` doesn't.

Like you, I switched to `FileSystemLoader` for this case, but I added a conditional to continue using `PackageLoader` when possible.  That allows `python -m path.to.my.module` to continue working if the module is installed in a ZIP file or egg:

```py
if __spec__ is not None:
    loader = jinja2.PackageLoader('__main__')
else:
    loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(
        os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
    )
env = jinja2.Environment(loader=loader)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered that FileSystemLoader still works and looks more appropriate for my use anyway.